# Paypal Donations - "Gift Aid"

Tags: api, paypal

Implementing Paypal for a UK based NGO where they are selling certain services plus accepting donations.

1. I am using REST API for selling services which is working well but do we use the same API for Donation as well. I would like to handle Gift Aids as well. I dont see any payment type option within the API.
2. If I use the standard Donation button, how do I get the transaction Id and other values back so that I can save them in my system.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real technical difference between donations and payments for goods and services. (The donations button is just a few cosmetic differences on top of a regular website payments standard or EC payment experience.) The REST is not yet as feature rich as the older payment flows and may not have those same cosmetic tweaks available, but you can definitely use either the REST or the classic API for both services and donations.

I would recommend not using both REST and classic together on your site; you will encounter many annoyances due to differences in the underlying models. It is not just the initial payment integration that is different; the payment IDs are different, the APIs you can use to manage the payment lifecycle are different etc.

As one such example, to answer your question #2 you cannot get REST-style payment IDs for non-REST transactions. You get back classic transaction IDs in the payment redirect or the DoEC API response, depending upon which integration you use. You also get classic payment IDs if you integrate IPNs (whereas with REST you would integrate webhooks... the differences keep coming!).